# Array index is missing when converting to param string

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to conovert simple array to params string

```
$j.param({ instances: [1, null, null, null, null, null, null] })
```

however the output is

```
instances%5B%5D=1&
instances%5B1%5D=null&
instances%5B2%5D=null&
instances%5B3%5D=null&
instances%5B4%5D=null&
instances%5B5%5D=null&
instances%5B6%5D=null
```

that gets converted to

```
instances[]=1
instances[1]=null
instances[2]=null
instances[3]=null
instances[4]=null
```

Why the first element is missing it's index?
I'm using jQuery v1.7.2

Comment: i'm surprised there's an array index at all. that goes against the current documentation unless i'm not interpreting it correctly. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with first element http://jsfiddle.net/UfXH6/

Comment: `$j.param({ instances: [1, '', '', '', '', '', ''] })` works fine, thank you for comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$j.param({ instances: [1, '', '', '', '', '', ''] })
```

works fine, thank you all for comments!